# KVM Disksize&RAM for Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I wish to follow this steps 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/

I will setup the KVM - but how much RAM and Diskspace should be added?
I think to run just a couple of Docker like Plex.

have a nice day
vinc

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend starting with 4GB memory and 10 GB disk space.  If you want better performance you need allocate more memory depending upon application requirements.